# Skyrim clocks (game clock and real clock)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

How can I check Skyrim time without looking in the saved games details? Is there a way to always have it on the screen?

Second clock that I need is a normal clock with my PC time. Is there a way to show it on the screen?

Patches / Fix / Mods allowed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### [KenMOD - Time on loading screen](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/98)

by [Kenney](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/users/440451)

**Features**

- Current computer time on loading screens.
- (optional) Blank screen to avoid spoilers.

[image]

### Skyrim time

- Hit 'T' or whatever you assigned to 'wait'. It shows the current time and day of the week.

Answer (score 5):

With out mods, since the game is run through steam, you can hit Shift-Tab at any time to see your real time, its at the top of the overlay. You can also see in-game time by pausing the game though I will admit hitting the wait button (as long as its available to be hit) is the preferred way for me to check in-game time as well.

Answer (score 1):

I can use the [A Matter of Time](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/44091) mod to display in-game time, day, date, and year. This helps me to see how many years have passed in-game and I still have not saved the world (er touched the main quest).

I also use it to display real-life time.

It has a MCM menu that I use to configure everything including the position of the clock widgets on my HUD.

It is also available for [Skyrim Special Edition](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/12937).

Both of these require [SkyUI](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/3863) or [SkyUI for SSE](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/12604) and [SKSE](https://skse.silverlock.org/).